# Almost sure inequality and the supremum

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

I've been reading about convergence lately and I've found that most books assume the following without explaining:

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables, if $|X_n|\leq Y$ almost surely for all $n$ then $sup\phantom{.}_n \phantom{a} |X_n|\leq Y$ almost surely too.

Can someone give a quick proof about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n$, let $A_n=\{ \omega : \vert X_n(\omega)\vert \leq Y(\omega)\}$. By hypothesis we know that the probability of $A_n$ is $1$ for each $n$. Then consider
$$ A= \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n $$
$A$ is still a measurable set of probability $1$ (by standard properties of the measure, the complementary is a countable union of sets of probability $0$) and for each $\omega\in A$ we have $\vert X_n(\omega)\vert\leq Y$ for all $n$, so also $\sup_n \vert X_n(\omega)\vert \leq Y$.

Comment: I don't understand the relation between the set $A$ and the supremum, besides I think that the supremum is taken over the random variable (so is the supremum of a function)

Comment: The supremum is taken over $n$. Each $X_n$ is a random variable (or if you want a measurable function), and the supremum over $n$ defines pointwise another random variable (or again measurable function), i.e. $\sup_n \vert X_n\vert$ is defined by $\sup_n \vert X_n\vert (\omega) = \sup_n \vert X_n(\omega)\vert$

Comment: Yes you are right, now the idea is to prove that this random variable is in fact less than or equal to $Y$ almost surely....

Comment: That’s what I did in fact. I showed that there exists a set, namely $A$, such that $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ and such that, for all $\omega\in A$, $\sup_n \vert X_n(\omega)\vert \leq Y(\omega)$. This means exactly that the inequality holds almost surely.

Comment: Oh sorry took some time to digest. You are absolutely right,

Comment: No problem, happy to help you.