# Almost sure convergence for absolute value of random variables and inequalities and supremums

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum, almost-everywhere

I read this article about almost sure inequality and the supremum from [Almost sure inequality and the supremum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488304/almost-sure-inequality-and-the-supremum)

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables, if $\left|X_n \right| \leq Y$ almost surely for all $n$, then $\sup \left| X_n \right| \leq Y$ almost surely.

Is it true that if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, then $|X| \leq \sup_{k \geq 1} \left| X_{n_k} \right| \leq \sup \left|X_n \right| \leq Y$ where $X_{n_k}$ is a subsequence?

Comment: Why would you have $\sup \left|X_n \right| \leq \left| X_n \right|$ ? By definition this is not true in general

Comment: Sorry, was typing too quickly cause I was in a rush

Comment: Ok and you haven't defined $X$ either

Comment: $X_n \to X$ in probability is what you also need?

Comment: Seems correct. ${}$

Comment: You can also proceed directly, with probability $p_n$ tending to one, $X \leq X_n + \varepsilon$ so $|X| \leq |Y| + \varepsilon.$ So, $|X| \leq |Y| + \varepsilon$ with probability 1, now let $\varepsilon = 1/k$ and let $k \to \infty.$

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. So simple. I overthink things 